# How to get a contact's facebook id or url from native contacts / content resolver?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider, facebook

**How to get the facebook id or url of a contacts that's been synced to the native contacts app via Facebook sync adapter?**

I went through different urls, but didn't see any info regarding facebook.

I tried

```
ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
```

as URIs already in the code below:

```
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        for (int i=0; i<c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, c.getColumnName(i) + ": " +  c.getString(i));
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "==================================");

    }
```

I do get a column value like

```
contact_status_res_package: com.facebook.katana
```

in this dump, and I also get the contacts status (contact_status column), but nowhere do I see the facebook url or id of this contact.

Comment: If you start the facebook application through your profile the following intent gets started. der intent sieht folgendermaßen aus: 12-22 08:59:27.083: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/4121 cmp=com.facebook.katana/.ProfileTabHostActivity } This looks like there is a raw data row that represents the facebook account. But accessing a row with this id returns an empty cursor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got the reply from on the Google Group (http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/95110dd7a1e1e0b4):

> Access to Facebook friends via the
>   contacts provider is restricted to a 
>   handful of system apps by the provider
>   itself. Other applications cannot 
>   read that data.

Therefore now I fetch an cache all contact names/id mappings via FB Graph api (http://graph.facebook.com/me/friends) and use that for the id lookup.

Comment: Can you please post the code of how you use contact's name to get the fb id?