# How to get/query contact's facebook name?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app I need to get profile pictures of favorite contacts who have their Facebook account synced. In order to do that I need to get the contact's Facebook name, or profile web address, and then download the pictures through the Facebook-Graph.

I have searched the web but found no answers.

I have a contact which is sycned with his Facebook account, How do I get his Facebook user id or name in order to do this?

Comment: Mr. It's not *a real question*.

Comment: The question is how do I get the contact's facebook user id? or name?

Comment: I've edited this a bit. I can make sense out of it. In the future, try reading your questions out loud before posting as a last check to make sure they 'sound' the way that you intend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a contact's facebook id or url from native contacts / content resolver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506571/how-to-get-a-contacts-facebook-id-or-url-from-native-contacts-content-resolve)

Answer (score 1):

https://graph.facebook.com/*$facebookUserId*/picture

Comment: Yea, that my question, how do I get contact's facebookUserId?

Comment: I know how to download the picture with a given id, the problem is that I don't know how to get the $facebookUserId of a given contact. I have his contact id\lookup_key, but have no idea how to query/get his $facebookUserId.

Comment: Did you find a solution on this one?